# ImageMagick Implement a specific convert command in Imagick (PHP)

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

Is there any ImageMagick expert over here?

I'm trying to implement the following command in Imagick (PHP):

```
convert ./Test.png -size 1x1 xc:#ffbf00 -fx 'u*v.p{0,0}' TestOutput.png
```

I've tried to implement that, but I couldn't.

Can anyone assist?

**[UPDATE] Solution:**

Thanks to Mark Setchell that helped to find a much faster way by using a different cloning & painting functions.
The implemented version in PHP

```
$img1 = new \Imagick();
$img1->readImage(realpath("./Testing.png"));

$img2 = clone $img1;
$img2->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
$img2->setImageBackgroundColor('#ffff29');
$img2->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SHAPE);

$img1->compositeImage($img2, \Imagick::COMPOSITE_MULTIPLY, 0, 0);
$img1->writeImage('./Testing2.png');
```

Thanks a lot fellas!

Comment: What is it supposed to do? Multiply every pixel in `Test.png` by yellow? What's the point?

Comment: `-fx` is a bit slow and harder to use - you can likely get the same result by copying the input image (you will get another image the same size) and filling the copy with yellow and then doing a `multiply` composite. At the command line that would be `convert Test.png \( +clone -fill "#ffbf00" -colorize 100% \) -compose multiply -composite  result.png`

Comment: @MarkSetchell, well done, 100 times faster than -fx and works perfectly! Appreciate your help guys.